# why use `+start` instead of `start` in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.7.0/lodash.src.js#L2781

What does  `+start` mean in this snippet `start = start == null ? 0 : (+start || 0);`?

In my opinion, `+start` equals `0+start`. and we'v already known `start` is a number.

so why not use  `start = start == null ? 0 : (start || 0);`?

Is there anything I misunderstand.? I am really confused.

Comment: The only thing you know is that it's neither `null` nor `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't know, at the start of that method, that `start` is a number. The documentation says it *ought to be*, but when has the documentation always been exactly right?

There isn't any real difference between `+start` and `0+start`, as both will coerce `start` into a number (so will `-start`, but it obviously inverts the sign in the process).

Assuming the docs are right and `start` is already a number, `+start` is a no-op and doesn't cause any problems or break anything. If `start` is not a number (the next most likely type is probably string), then this will coerce it into a number before using it.